# How to implement a singleton in a static library

Tags: c++, linux, architecture

I have a question regarding how does a singleton in a static library (.a/.lib) behave.

```
class MySingleton {
public:
     static
     MySingleton& 
     GetInstance() {
         static MySingleton singleton;
         return singleton;
     }
private:
     explicit
     MySingleton() {}

     virtual
     ~MySingleton() {}
};
```

How can you make sure that on OS level, there is ONLY ONE MySingleton if you use static library?

As you may know, static library has multiple copies in memory. Do those copies interfere with each other or totally irrelevant? Meaning if you have app1 and app2, does app1 has one MySingleton and app2 also has one MySingleton?

How can you meet the requirement that if once app1 starts up and consumes MySingleton, app2 has no chance to create another MySingleton even it holds another copy of static library.

Comment: You might be able to use a named semaphore (http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open) to achieve this behaviour. I don't know enough about named semaphores under Linux to help you any further, though.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Why do you want to?

Comment: Let me try to elaborate on my comment: If you manage to marshal the state of your singleton instance for some IPC and then used a (named) semaphore to make other processes aware of existing instances you might be able to simulate what you've described without actually needing to share memory. Isn't sharing state sufficient?

Comment: Each running program (or process) will have its own data including any static singletons. They are unique to the program (or process). This is usually what you want. If you want to share a single object between programs (processes) then you may have to do some clever stuff with *shared memory*. For example your *singleton* could store its data in *shared memory* giving the illusion of one singleton (but hiding the *shared memory* access from the rest of the program), or you could instantiate your singleton in *shared memory*.

Comment: I think the design/architecture is questionable at least. First, Singletons are nowadays considered as an anti-pattern. They are the OO implementation of global variables, with all the drawbacks, and in C++ you get more trouble because of static initialization hell. Second, if you have something that both processes share, I would put it in a separate process which communicates with clients, e.g. via IPC, pipes, messages, shared memory etc. This process can be started automatically, and e.g. use a lock file. Or you start the process as a daemon and let the OS handle it.

Comment: Thanks! @Jens. I think I have to give up the singleton idea for static library design.

Comment: @minghua I am a fan of the service idea. Create a small daemon which is managed by the OS (if it is Linux, for Windows it could be a Service?), and communicate with it via some IPC means. Personally, I like message-passing and would look at zeroMQ, but there could other technologies which are more appropriate to your use-case.

Comment: @Jens, thanks for your info about zeroMQ, I'd have a look.

Answer (score 1):

At a OS level, Processes do not share any memory, apart from shared libraries.
Process A will have its own instance  of your singleton and Process B will have a completely different instance of singleton and both the processes are isolated from each other.

If you want any logic that involves multiple processes, then think along the lines of a shared library/shared memory.

Comment: Even shared libraries don't share their address space (except for code).

Comment: agree with that..this is difficult/not possible to acheive even with shared libraries...

Comment: i am not sure about this but maybe can be acheived through some shared memory mapping between processes

Comment: Thanks for explanation! @basav